# Checkboxes in a pandas dataframe plot

Tags: python, pandas, checkbox, graph

i have the problem that i want to display a dataset which i import with read_csv from pandas. I can display it in a line chart, thats fine but i want also to select the lines i want to see that the user can filter itself. For that i wanted to implement checkboxes but i dont find a good example on the internet how to make it with a pandas dataframe. I've found some examples with matplotlib but i wasnt able to do it so with a pandas dataframe. The thing is that i dont know how much columns the dataset will have when  the programm imports it. The only known thing about the csv data is that the first column will be the x axis because it contains date and time. As i said the plot itself works, but i dont know how to implement checkboxes for each line. Maybe somebody could help me, thank you all in advance!

Comment: I think one way to go is to present your dataset with Jupyter. Perhaps the framework [Mito](https://www.trymito.io/) can be something for you although I don’t think it supports checkboxes. You could also try ipywidgets, and a larger effort seems to implement something in a Python UI framework like PyQT.

Comment: Thank you, i tried it now with an standard csv with defined columns so i dont have to make the code intelligent, but i will try jupyter also, thanks!

Comment: So which GUI framework are you using?

Comment: I tried it now with matplotlib because i found an example in the documentation but it doesnt work. There seems to be a problem between some datatypes and the ability of matplotlib to plot these datatypes when they are in matrices. I'll go with the excel solution at the moment because of time but thank you for your trying.